# Using field variable to calculate values in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am using ModelBuilder and trying to get a user defined field from a user defined polygon.
From this, I want to later populate a different field with calculated values in a model.

Is there a way to get a list of fields from the user defined polygon and use that value to populate the other field?

How would I go about using the user defined field in a VB expression within the calculate value tool?

`newfield = [%field%]`?

Comment: It might be helpful to post a screenshot of your model here. 
Have you looked at all into Python?

Comment: That expression should work, if you have a text parameter called "field". Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, that should work, but why? There is so much danger in doing it this way as you're not picking a field from the feature class you're entering a string - a chance for typo's. Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do and hopefully I can come up with something a bit more robust.

Comment: By a "user-defined polygon" are you meaning a Feature Set?  And what do you mean by a "user-defined field"?  Perhaps including some screenshots will make your question clearer.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a field picker you have to code it in python.

The code is as follows:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set the parameters
InputFeatureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
InputField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

arcpy.SetParameter(2, InputField)
```

And the tool is set as follows:

Input Feature Layer

- Data Type: Feature Layer (You might be using a Feature Set)
- Direction: Input
- Multivalue: No

Inputs Fields

- Data Type: Fields
- Direction: Input
- Multivalue: No
- Obtained from: Input Feature Layer

Output Field

- Data Type: Field
- Direction: Output
- Multivalue: No

It looks like this

[image: Toolbox Script dialog]

You should then be able to use this to return a field as a FIELD object, suitable for a input parameter to the Calculate Field tool.
A model looks like this:
[image: Example Model]

I hope that helps.

Comment: What a clever solution. Too bad model builder doesn't inherently support the 'obtained from' option in the parameter settings.\